# Linear relations between statistics in exponential family of distributions

Tags: estimation, exponential-family, curved-exponential-family

I am reading about point estimation from [Theory of Point Estimation](https://amzn.to/3gFeToh) by Lehmann and Casella (1999).
I couldn't understand the following point mentioned in p.24, under the exponential family of distributions :

> An exponential family of distributions of dimension $s$ (in canonical
> form) is the set of distributions $p_\theta$ such that. $p_\theta =
>   h(x) . \exp[\sum_{i=1}^s \{\eta_iT_i(x) - A(\eta)\}]$.

It is mentioned that if the $\{T_i(x)\} $'s are linearly dependent (i.e one of $T_i(x)$ can be written as a linear combination of others) then the number of parameters of $\eta_i$ can be reduced (from $s$ to $s-1$). I understand why this is so.

What I don't understand is the following:

> **"if the $\{T_i(x)\}$ are linearly dependent, then the corresponding parameters $\{\eta_i\}$ cannot be estimated individually."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the $T_i$'s are linearly dependent, the model is *not identifiable*, that is, there exist several parameters $\eta=(\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_s)$ producing the *same* density. Indeed, if there exists a vector $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s)\ne(0,\ldots,0)$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1} \alpha_i T_i(\cdot) \equiv 0$$
then
$$\sum_{i=1} \eta_i T_i(\cdot) \equiv \sum_{i=1} \{\alpha_i+\eta_i\} T_i(\cdot)$$
which means that $\eta$ and $\eta+\alpha$ lead to the same density function.

Comment: Yeah. I get that the model is unidentifiable but I don't understand why if distributions are the same for different parameter values, the parameters cannot be estimated. Can you provide some intuition for that?

Comment: I am afraid my intuition stops at the fact that if several values of the parameter $\eta$ returns the same distribution/density, I cannot hope to estimate this parameter consistently.